# Regex explode sql query

Tags: php, regex

i have spent searching and finding a solution for my problem the entire day and couldn't find anything for my Problem. I have a query which needs to be "exploded" via regular expression. I want to get the selected fields, the table and the fields after the where condition (without the check itself).

```
SELECT `a`, `b`, `c` FROM `d` WHERE `e` > 1 OR `d` > 1
```

My attempt looks like the following:

```
/SELECT (?<selectedFields>(,*?)\`(.*?)\`) FROM (?<tableName>\`(.*?)\`) WHERE (?<checkFields>\`(.*?)\`)/
```

The Problem I have is that the regular expression stops after the first field at the where condition. The Output i got looks like the following.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT `a`, `b`, `c` FROM `d` WHERE `e`
    )

[selectedFields] => Array
    (
        [0] => `a`, `b`, `c`
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => `a`, `b`, `c`
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => a`, `b`, `c
    )

[tableName] => Array
    (
        [0] => `d`
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => `d`
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => d
    )

[checkFields] => Array
    (
        [0] => `e`
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => `e`
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => e
    )

)
```

I need the "checkFields" in the same kind of array i got the selected fields. What am i doing wrong? Second thing is that the selectFields from the regular expression are not as expected an array with each fieldname, it is separated by ','...

Comment: You can use this project: http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/

Comment: get the \`inside the parenthesis...

Answer (score 4):

You should not parse sql query with regex, because parsing sql query with regex is very similar of parsing html with regex. And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1283847) clearly says why you should not do it.

You'd better use some parser (e.g. [this one](http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/)).

Little sample:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `a`, `b`, `c` FROM `d` WHERE `e` > 1 OR `d` > 1';
$sqlParser = new PHPSQLParser($sql);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($sqlParser->parsed);
```

Comment: Humm... I do not want to use a sql parser because all of my queries i have to explode are made without any join, alias or whatever. I have to repair some broken data fields and because i do not want to copy mysql_query, mysql_fetch_assoc a hundred times i just thought that it might be possible get around with a regular expression.

Comment: @Christian, It's possible to use regular exception for given query but exactly the same query maybe little bit different as a string and regular exception will fail.

Comment: the problem is that the regular expression won't gather all elements. It stops after the first element of the where part. Instead of returing e and d at "checkFields", the result is only e...
 
    $sRegPattern = '/SELECT(?<selectFields>(.*?))FROM(?<tableNames>(.*?))WHERE(?<checkFields>(.*))/s';
 
     $sSpecificResult = '/\`(.*?)\`/';
For getting all elements i have to run 2 regular expression (above). Is it possible to combine them?

Answer (score 1):

With REGEX you won't go too far.  Think about all possible SQL queries:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 
SELECT field as field2 FROM table1 as alias
etc
```

You need a parser for this. Try: http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/

Also I would even recommend you to don't parse SQL at all, SQL parser builtin in a database are very very complex and mimic their behaviors isn't easy.

If you need such behaviour you can create a simple Class that does the inverse (builds up your SQL), something like:

```
$s = new SQL();
$s->setFrom('table');
$s->addCondition('condition1','value1');
$s->select('*');  //> outputs SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition1 = 'value1'
```

So you can have a method to retrieve all parts:

```
$s->getConditions();
$s->getSelect();
```